# python seaborn plotting using index when index has some missing values

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe as below. Index is blank for some rows. I want to plot it and my code is as below

1. i am struggling with `marker` It is appearing only for few points - how could i show all the points?
2. How could I rotate x axis labels. I tried the last line that i have commented.

`lst = [5,10,8,7,8,4,6,8,9]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(lst, index =['a', '', '', 'd', '', '', '','e','f'], columns =['Names'])`

`df`

[image]

```
#how to show poings with missing index and how to rotate x axis labels by 90 degree?

import seaborn as sns
#sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(20,10)})
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
plot=sns.lineplot(data=df['Names'],marker='o')
#plot.set_xticklabels(plot.get_xticklabels(),rotation = 30)
```

[image]

Comment: Some of your index has no names. It is logically impossible to represent those points if some of the labels are missing. If these information is necessary on your plot, you have to give a labels to those datapoints with no labels. Otherwise, you can use `df = df.reset_index(drop=False)` to create a dummy index of [0, 1, 2, ..., n].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dummy `np.arange` for the x-axis, and then relabel the x-axis.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': [5, 10, 8, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 9]},
                  index=['a', '', '', 'd', '', '', '', 'e', 'f'])
ax = sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(df)), y=df['Names'].values, marker='o')
ax.set_xticks([x for x, lbl in enumerate(df.index) if lbl != ''])
ax.set_xticklabels([lbl for lbl in df.index if lbl != ''], rotation=30)
ax.grid(True, axis='x')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with dummy x-axis]

Comment: is there a way to show vertical gridlines associated with index which are not blank?